# UILabel does not update upon clicking a cell in TableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS development and I'm trying to build a dictionary. My first screen just has a search bar on top and a `TableView` of all the entries underneath. When you type in the search bar, the TableView is filtered with the entries that match. When you click on any of the cells either in list-all mode or filtered mode, another view is pushed showing the name of the word and the definition.

I am already able to open a new screen whenever I click on the table cells, but for some reason, the two labels in the new screen (the word and the definition) just won't be updated with the selection--it stays empty. I think I've correctly set up these two `IBOutlet`s in my XIB file though, because when I log the `text` attributes of the `UILabel`s, they print out correctly. Help?

EntryViewController.h (the second screen):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EntryViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *word;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *definition;

@end
```

EntryViewController.m:

```
#import "EntryViewController.h"

@implementation EntryViewController

@synthesize word, definition;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    self.word = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.definition = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

UTVTViewController.h (the first screen):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EntryViewController.h"

@interface UTVTViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,
    UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *sampleTableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *entries;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *sortedWords, *filteredList;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isSearching;
@property (nonatomic, retain) EntryViewController *entryView;

- (void)filterListForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText;

@end
```

UTVTViewController.m

```
#import "UTVTViewController.h"
#import "EntryViewController.h"

@implementation UTVTViewController

@synthesize sampleTableView, entries, sortedWords, filteredList, isSearching, entryView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    entries = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [entries setObject:@"a syndrome of wide spaced eyes (ocular hypertelorism), front-facing (anteverted) nostrils, a broad upper lip, a malformed (\"saddle-bag\") scrotum, and laxity of the ligaments resulting in bending back of the knees (genu recurvatum), flat feet, and overly extensible fingers. There are X-linked and autosomal forms of the disease. The gene for the X-linked form has been mapped to chromosome band Xp11.21 and identified as the FGD1 gene." forKey:@"aarskog-scott syndrome"];
    [entries setObject:@"a diminution, decrease or easing. In medicine there may be abatement of pain or any other symptom or sign. In the environment there may abatement in the degree of pollution" forKey:@"abatement"];
    [entries setObject:@"a disorder marked by a pathological pattern of alcohol use that causes serious impairment in social or occupational functioning. It includes both alcohol abuse and alcohol dependence." forKey:@"alcoholism"];
    // ...other words

    sortedWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[entries allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
    filteredList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    isSearching = NO;
}

// ...

#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *selection;
    if (isSearching && [filteredList count]) {
        selection = [filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        selection = [sortedWords objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    EntryViewController *evc = [[EntryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EntryView" bundle:nil];
    evc.title = selection;

    [evc.word setText:selection];
    [evc.definition setText:[entries objectForKey:selection]];
    NSLog(@"word=%@", evc.word.text);
    NSLog(@"definition=%@", evc.definition.text);

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:evc animated:YES];
}

@end
```

**EDIT:** I'm including the header and implementation files for the AppDelegate. I have a feeling the error is somewhere in the `navigationController` which I have currently not connected to anything, but I don't even know where to attach it since I don't have one in my XIB.

UTVTAppDelegate.h:

```
@interface UTVTAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UTVTViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

UTVTAppDelegate.m

```
@implementation UTVTAppDelegate

@synthesize navigationController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[UTVTViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UTVTViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

// default Xcode methods

@end
```

Comment: You don't need to `synthesize` anymore, it is automatically done so you gotta use the synthesizen-variables with an underscore before them.

Comment: Which ones do I no longer have to synthesize?

Comment: all of the variables you are synthesizing. Remove the whole `@synthesize` line and put an underscore before every variable you synthesized in the first place that you currently use.

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't show my labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, I was setting the `UILabel`'s texts before pushing the view controller to the navigation controller. Solution:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:evc animated:YES];
[evc.word setText:selection];
[evc.definition setText:[entries objectForKey:selection]];
```

I also removed the lines in my code where I called `alloc` on detached `UILabel` objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you created your UILabels through xib, you shouldn't realloc it in init.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
self.word = [[UILabel alloc] init];//REMOVE
self.definition = [[UILabel alloc] init];//REMOVE
return self;
```

}

Comment: But deleting the two lines makes the two `UILabel`s `nil`, so still no text shows. Does that mean I haven't connected them correctly to the XIB?

Comment: It seems so, because the xib connections handle your labels' allocation. There should be filled dots on the left of 
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *word; 
line. If it is filled, it should be connected.

Comment: ^Interestingly enough, the dots beside each `@property` are filled. :( I actually deleted my own declarations and Ctrl-dragged from the IB to the Assistant Editor to recreate the variables `word` and `definition`. Still no show. Even my File's Owner is set to `EntryViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
self.word = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.definition = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

you create new objects that are detached from the UI.  When the NIB is loaded, all UI objects are created for you, and your IBOutlet properties are initialised with them.  Just remove these two lines and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the navigationcontroller as rootviewController of window, instead of adding it as subview.

```
@implementation UTVTAppDelegate

@synthesize navigationController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[UTVTViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UTVTViewController" bundle:nil];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;`?